# Understanding Function prototypes

Tags: c, arrays, argument-passing, function-parameter

Are the function prototypes

```
int sum_array(int array[], int arr_length);
```

and

```
int sum_array(int [], int arr_length);
```

similar?
If yes then, what does `int []` mean?
Can i define above prototypes by swapping their positions,i.e

```
 int sum_array( int arr_length, int array[]);
```

?
**NOTE**:I have no idea about pointers(sorry for that).

Comment: In a prototype, `int a_very_long_name[]`, `int a_long_name[]`, `int a_name[]`, `int a[]`, and `int []` all mean the same thing.

Comment: @JimBalter; But i think in last one i.e `int []`, has no variable name .

Comment: Yes ... what's your point? The variable name isn't used in a prototype (in most cases, such as this one; there are exceptions), it's just for clarity / documentation. You've already read the answers and accepted one, so you should know this by now.

Comment: My point is clear......i was confused with `int []`. I thought that how it is representing an array without a variable name.

Comment: Not much of what you write is clear ... that last sentence certainly isn't.

Comment: I mean to say in prototype `int sum(int , int );`, `int` inside the parenthesis indicates that it is expecting `int` type arguments.Similarly in above cases `int []` is also representing **type** of argument(first) which must be of **integer array type**.When i encountered `int []` first time i was not aware that it is representing a type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C standard states that you MAY declare identifiers for the parameters in the function prototype, but you don't have to.

> The identifiers ... are declared for descriptive purposes only and go out of scope at the end of the declaration

So to answer your first question, there is essentially no difference between the first two prototypes. And `int []` means "an array of integers", in a similar way that `int array[]` means "an array of integers identified as `array`".

The third prototype also works, but the variables will be pushed on the stack the opposite order. You can do this as long as the prototype and definition use the same ordering.

Comment: That means swapping will work if arguments passed by function call swapped to?

Comment: Exactly; otherwise you should get a compiler error, because it would appear to the compiler that you were trying to use an `int` in place of an `int[]` and vice-versa.

Comment: Got it! +1 for third para.

Comment: Arguments aren't necessarily pushed onto a stack. All that is relevant is that all the prototypes and calls must agree.

Answer (score 4):

Both prototypes are the same. The first one just give a name to the first parameter :

```
int sum_array(int array[], int arr_length);
```

or

```
int sum_array(int [], int arr_length);
```

are the same. Naming the parameters in prototype is just for information purpose only.

In the same way, you can do :

```
int sum_array(int [], int);
```

After that the implementation will look like :

```
int sum_array(int array[], int arr_length)
{ ... }
```

But you can't swap the parameters, that is not the same thing.
If you swap the parameters, the implementation and the calls to this function must have the parameters swapped too.

Comment: what is the meanig of `int []`??

Comment: It just says to the compiler that the parameter will be an array of `int`. It is the same as `int array[]`, but here you give a name to the parameter for descriptive purpose. I prefer naming the parameters in my prototype, it make the reading of header files easier for me.